# How can Blockchain be used for Provenance purposes?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I do not understand how Blockchain can be used to prove the provenance of a product? I have read several articles which talked about tracking of a product from its birth until its death. I got a few questions based on my understanding of how cryptocurrencies work.

- When a product is manufactured, how does that history get into the blockchain? I would assume an RFID which is scanned and the information put on the blockchain
- If that is the case, can that data not be manipulated as well? As an example, a product is manufactured today, but the RFID is scanned tomorrow given an incorrect birth date
- The same goes with every hop where scanning is delayed in terms of time

How does Blockchain solve the problem of provenance based on above questions.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main goals of blockchain based cryptocurrencies is the fact that there are no "copies". Every token exists exactly once. If you send 10 tokens to another address it is guaranteed that the senders balance get reduced `= -10` and the receivers balance get this and exactly this 10 tokens `= +10` (for example). The receiver will not get 10 digital different tokens. Like a unique bank not that exists only once. You dont have the same bank not twice. You may have another 10$ bank not, but not the same.
And the whole transfer proccess is monitored, executed and documented on a decentralized blockchain. No middleman or clearing station (where things could get manipulated) is necessary. So its highly trustful and valid.

Cryptocurrencies are only one possible use case.

The same could be possible with a product. For example a product will be transferred from one to another (manufacturer
to a retailer).

Of course there are a lot of difficulties to handle: How to monitor if every real (offline-) transfer (to ship a coconut from the farmer to the manufacturer) got triggered the right way?

I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks [q0re](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2746429/q0re) for the insight helpful. Ive edited my question above for more details based on your answer and my deeper understanding